# MS Access - Updating a cell's value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

My customer wants to be able to autosum values within a cell. For example, they type in a new value, and this value will be added to the previous one, all within one cell (they don't want another field).

So far, I have 2 forms that will calculate the new value with one they input into the *calculator*, but it only functions for one cell.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Function MyVal(lnIn As Long)
    If Len(Me.entry) > 1 Then
        Me.entry = Replace(Me.entry, ".", "") & lnIn
        'Me.entry = Left(Me.entry, Len(Me.entry)) & "." & Right(Me.entry)
    Else
        Me.entry = Me.entry & lnIn
    End If
End Function

Private Sub calc_Click()
    Me.Balance = Me.Balance - (-(Me.entry))
    Me.entry = ""
End Sub

Private Sub clear_Click()
    Me.entry = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Command16_Click()
    Dim MyBalance As Currency
    MyBalance = Me.Balance
    DoCmd.Close
    Forms!frmHours.Form.SetFocus
    Forms!frmHours.Form.Balance = MyBalance
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Balance = OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Is there a way to move the "selected" cell value into the table I have (replacing the old value), do the calculations, and then move the new value back into the selected cell?

Comment: Removed redundant remarks

Comment: Its really difficult to tell what you mean with the information provided. But you can most likely solve your problem using some sort of temporary `integer` or `double` variable to hold the value. And replace it once your calculations are complete (whatever those may be).